# How to export test cases from one .side file and import in another .side file on New Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium-ide

I want to export some test cases from one of my **.side** files and then import those test cases to another **.side** file (in New Selenium IDE). I mean I want to merge two .side files. Is there any way to do it?

I tried to export but it allows to export for different platform like: C# NUnit C# xUnit Java JUnit
Python pytest Ruby RSpec, which does not work for me.